# The value returned by ngResource cannot be passed to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service

eventservice.js:

```
angular.module('staApp')
.factory('EventsService', function($resource) { // Value returned correctly
    return $resource('http://....azurewebsites.net/api/events/getlist');
});
```

The webapi call return a valid json result when debugging using Chrome developer tools.

```
[{"Id":22,"EventName":"xxx","TimeStart":"2016-04-22T22:00:00","Price":0.0000,"ImageUrl":"~/Content/Event/thumb_07e3467d-f0a4-470b-91bc-523981fdcb82.png","VenueId":9572},
 {"Id":23,.....
```

And in the controller events.js

```
angular.module('aApp')
  .controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, EventsService) {

    $scope.events = EventsService.query(); // The length of $scope.events is 0; tried get() but got a different error

    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

When debugging in Chrome, it showed that the length of `$scope.events` is zero. Why the controller couldn't get the data?

And the view code is:

```
<h1>Title is shown in the page</h1>
<div ng-repeat="event in events" style=" background-image:url( {{event.ImageUrl}} )">
    test <!-- this only show once while five times are expected -->
    <div id="events-li-info_box">
        {{event.EventName}}
        <div class="events-li-info_bttm-row">
            {{event.TimeStart}} 
            {{event.Price}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ever consider using a `$promise` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
angular.module('aApp')
  .controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, EventsService) {
   $scope.entries = EventsService.query(function() {
     console.log($scope.entries);
   })

    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

**HTML VIEW:**

```
<div ng-controller="EventsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="event in entries " class="back-cover" style=" background-image:url( {{event.ImageUrl}} )">
        <div id="events-li-info_box">
            {{event.EventName}}
            <div class="events-li-info_bttm-row">
                {{event.TimeStart}} 
                {{event.Price}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It did print out the data from the webapi call. And I added `$scope.events = entries` after the entries are assigned. However, the view still didn't render the data.

Comment: have you used controller in your view ?

Comment: How I check if I've used controller in my view?

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working. I used yeoman to create the files and didn't add the ng-controller tag.

Comment: Its good to use yeoman for rapid developing and preventing issues like this.if i am correct in my opinion then up vote it